# How to make toast work in a class which doesn't extend activity?

Tags: android, class, onclicklistener, toast, android-toast

How do I make this

```
Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter a Number",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

work in a class which only

```
implements OnClickListener
```

How can I make it work without adding

```
extends Activity
```

The class its in is called

```
ButtonClickListener
```

which is called from the MainActivity

Comment: Pass a `Context` value of the `Activity` to the method which calling this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that, your ButtonClickListener class needs to have a Context value, and once you create an instance of that class in the MainActivity, you have to pass the Context. Maybe set a ButtonClickListener constructor that requires a Context.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class ButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener {
      ...
      private Context context;
      ...

      public ButtonClickListener(..., Context c) {
         ...
         context = c;
      }

     ...
     void showToast(String text) {
         Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
}
```

and in your `MainActivity.java` use this

```
CustomOnClickListener xyz = new CustomOnClickListener(...,MainActivity.this);
xyz.showToast("Please enter a Number");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can show toast by context

```
Toast.makeText(context,"Please enter a Number",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

just pass the context to constructor of ButtonClickListener and use that context.